# How to display error message?

Tags: php, html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
  <body>

  <?php

if (isset($_POST['txt'])) {

    $veggies = array("Potato", "Cucumber", "Carrot", "Orange", "Green Beans", "onion");
    $fruits  = array("Apple", "Banana", "orange", "Pineapple", "Grapes", "Watermelon");
    $salad   = array_merge ($veggies, $fruits);
    $Object = $_POST['txt'];
    $search = array_filter($salad, function($list) use ($Object) {
        return ( stripos($list, $Object) !== FALSE );
    });

      print_r($search);

         // echo '<pre>' . print_r($search) . '</pre>';
     } 

     else {
    echo " Nothing entered into the Search Item field ";
      }

   ?>

   <form method="POST"> 
     Search item:  <input type="text" name="txt" ><br> <br>
              <input type="submit">
  </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I have one small doubt, if i click submit button without entering any value in the text box it should show "Nothing entered into the Search Item field", instead its showing "Array()", how to fix this issue ??

Comment: Use `empty` instead of `isset`

Comment: it did not solved my problem.

Comment: Should be: use `!empty` instead of `isset`

Comment: can u please edit my code n paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual:

> A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value
>   equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does
>   not exist.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')) {
    if(!empty($_POST['txt'])) {
        // Do your thing
    } 
    else {
        echo " Nothing entered into the Search Item field ";
    }
}

?>
```

Whereas with isset:

```
$foo = '';
var_dump(isset($foo));
```

Outputs:

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: to some extent its working , i mean when i run the file, first only its displaying the result as "Nothing entered into the Search Item field", and when i click submit then also its " Nothing entered into the Search Item field ".

Comment: Don't know exactly what the rest of your code looks like.. But the function should only be triggered when post data is set, right? I'll update the answer.

Comment: i have pasted all my code above, please check n let me know if possible

Comment: Thank you i just tried what u told and it worked. Thank you lot

Comment: The conditional: `isset($_POST)` evaluates to `true` for me.  To check whether you have a http post request (from the form submission), try the following conditional: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`.

Comment: Could be version specific? It has been a while since I used those server constants...

Comment: Running that code there results in true because you post the form to execute the code...

Comment: False assumption.  Manual: "By default, all of the superglobals are available".  Try your code.